# Responsive div at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I have created the following HTML for the "footer" of my website:

```
<div class="author">Made by</div>
```

And the following CSS for author:

```
.author {
opacity: 0.2;
position: fixed;
top: 45.5vw;
left: 50vw;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-size: 0.8vw;
font-family: 'Hind Vadodara', sans-serif;
color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.author { 
top: 90%;
left: 50%;
font-size: 2.3vw;
}
}
```

I have tried a lot but when I  resize my window, the author does noet stay at the bottom of the page until it is switched to mobile view, how can I make the author text stay at the bottom at the same size when I resize the window?

Comment: I think I know what you're asking, but do you mean 'stay at the bottom of the page' (after all of the other content) or 'stay at the bottom of the viewport' (you can always see it)?

Comment: It needs to be visible at all times and the size should stay the same, with the current setup the text will become unreadable when I resize the window, it is only visible again when it switches to mobile view

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `bottom` to 0;

```
  .author {
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.author {
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  font-family: 'Hind Vadodara', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .author { 
    font-size: 2.3vw;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To stick it to  the bottom just use

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

and remove your top values in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how complicated is your layout, but you will have issues with just positioning to absolute. Try to use **flex** instead.

**The HTML**

```
<body class="Site">
  <header>…</header>
  <main class="Site-content">…</main>
  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```

**The CSS**

```
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Read more at https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/